# Change credentials in a function in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to change the credentials of state in a separate Javascript file which is a function() called `LoginConfirmation.js`. The credentials are in a class called `login.js`:

```
state = {
        credentials: {
            username: '',
            password: '',
            collapseID: '',
            logged_in: true,
            usernameChecked: LoginConfirmation.usernameChecked,
            passwordChecked: LoginConfirmation.passwordChecked
        },
        isLoginView: true,
        userAccount: []
    }
```

I am trying to change the values of `usernameChecked` and `passwordChecked` inside `LoginConfirmation.js` without using any HTML onChange or onClick etc.
I am mapping through my database using:

```
{props.userAccount.map(userAccount => { ...
```

And then setting:

```
let usernameChecked = userAccount.username
```

Is it possible to set this `usernameChecked` value to `usernameChecked` in the credentials in `login.js`

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing the entire set up.
But I guess you could add a public method to the class in `login.js` that makes the changes you want, something like (assuming it's a React class component, not a js class):

```js
updateUsernameChecked = (newValue) => {
  this.setState(state => state.credentials.usernameChecked = newValue);
}
```

then pass the method to `LoginConfirmation.js` and call it with the new value.

Hope this helps.